# Can a strict order relation imply an equality relation?

Tags: relations, order-theory

Let's assume we have a partial or total order relation $R$ defined on a set $S$.

If $R$ was not strict (i.e. it denoted $\leq$ instead of $<$), an equality relation $E$ could be defined as such:

$$
xEy:=xRy\land yRx
$$

In other words:

$$
x=y:=x\leq y\land y\leq x
$$

For all $x,y\in S$.

But if $R$ was strict (i.e. it denoted $<$ instead of $\leq$), I can't think of a way that $E$ could be defined using $R$. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Suppose your $R$ has $aRb, aRc, bRd, cRd$ so is a strict partial order.  This works whether or not $b=c$, since it is a partial order, so you cannot use this $R$ to define equality

Comment: @Henry would it work if $R$ was a total order? i.e. it was connected.

Comment: If it were a strict total order then you could conclude $b=c$ since you do not have $bRc$ and do not have $cRb$ and you must have one if it is total order and they are different - this is Robert Shore's answer

Answer (score 1):

For a total order, yes.  $xEy \iff (\lnot (x R y) \land \lnot (y R x))$.  I don't see any way to use a strict partial order to define equality.

Comment: Is it safe to say $\lnot(xRy)$ where R is strict is basically $yRx$ where R is not strict? In other words $\lnot(x<y) \iff y\leq x$

Comment: @SMMH In the context of a total order, yes, although you risk a ton of confusion if you use the same symbol ($R$) for both a strict and a non-strict order.

Comment: No need to worry, I only wrote them both as $R$ in this comment! By the way what notation would you suggest that would differentiate between a strict and a non-strict order? Perhaps $R$ and $R'$?

Comment: @SMMH Anything that's clear in context.  Your proposal would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. You are confusing $\vee$ with $\&$. What you want is that:

$$ x = y := x\leq y \ \& \ y \leq x$$.

But this only works if the set with the order relation on it is already known to be *connected*. That is:

$$x,y \in S \implies x \leq y \vee y \leq x $$

Also, there is no way that we can define equality simply in terms of strict-inequalities (by definition).

Comment: You are correct I had mistakenly typed $\lor$ instead of $\land$; I edited the question and fixed this. Can you take a look at the answer given by @Robert Shore?

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I can get:

Define $x_\lt =\{y | y \lt x\}$ and $x_\gt =\{y | y \gt x\}$, then the relation defined by

$$xRy \text{  iff } x_\lt = y_\lt \text{   and   } x_\gt = y_\gt$$

is definitely an equivalence, but I think you'd have to make other assumptions about your ordered set to make it coincide with equality.

Answer (score 0):

For general partial order, no, you can't.

Let $S=\{a,b\}$ and $R$ be the empty relation, i.e. we have that it is strict ($¬aRa$ and $¬bRb$) as well as $¬ aRb$ and $¬bRa$.

Now you can't distinguish between $a$ and $b$ using only without explicitly using the symbol $=$, that is: if $φ(x,y)$ is a formula that doesn't use $=$ then we have $φ(a,a)⇔φ(a,b)⇔φ(b,a)⇔φ(b,b)$